# No minyan at shul

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, minyan, tefillah-betzibbur

If a person goes to shul and there is no minyan (somewhere where there usually is one):

Does that person still have the same obligation to find another minyan?

Or, are there any opinions that hold that the person can say "I tried" and daven without a minyan?